# USB removable storage issues with HP Chromebook 11-2001TU

Tags: usb-storage, google-chrome-os

I have an HP Chromebook 11-2001TU running stock Chrome OS 51.0.2704.64 beta.

In Chrome OS, every time which I close the lid, or the system goes into standby, any USB drives are shut down, and only wake up when I open the lid.  The biggest issues occur when I have files open on the USB drive when it goes into standby.  When that happens, the previous "USB Drive", as well as a new "USB Drive 1" display in the chrome file manager, but there are henceforth no files accessible under "USB Drive", and files on that drive are only accessible under the new "USB Drive 1" from then onwards.

Sometimes Chrome also crashes and restarts.  A select subset of the log in `/var/log/messages` is at http://pastebin.com/CRU3vpqy if that provides any further details.

I have also experienced similar issues when running Arch Linux, where I lose and am unable to remount the OS partition when it resumes from standby.  Any pointers would be appreciated.